# Can I execute TestNG without an XML file?

Tags: java, testng

Most testing frameworks can be executed without an addition configuration file. E.g. execute all tests, a namespace, or a class. I have not found a way to execute testNG without a testNG.xml

Clarification:

I want to execute TestNG from a command line - manually or from a rake script, with a minimum (ideally no) XML.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, you can right-click on a package or class and select "Run As" -> "TestNG Test".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ant to execute your test cases in batch.You would just need to write a target for executing testng test cases in your build file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have plenty of options, starting by specifying classes, methods and groups on the command line, or with ant or with maven.

What you can do this way is fairly limited, though, and if you want to use advanced functionalities of TestNG, you will have to use a `testng.xml` file.

Personally, I like to have all my test information gathered in one central file instead of scattering it in my various build files. I don't want to change my build whenever I need to change the way my tests are running.

Comment: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng - All command line switches to add to the answer..